# Create Dynamic List Depends on Member

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dictionary

i needed something dynamic logic on saving dictionary under a dictionary

I have this separate list of Strings:

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string>();
    lstString.Add("Project.Beta.Version.Rule");
    lstString.Add("Project.Program.Table");
    lstString.Add("Project.Program");
    lstString.Add("Zip.File");
```

then foreach item , I split it by dot '.' to get their child:

e.g: 
**Rule** *--childOf-->* **Version** *--childOf-->* **Beta** *--childOf-->* **Project**

*in **Project.Beta.Version.Rule***

```
foreach(var item in lstString)
{
   string[] strSpl = item.Split('.');
}
```

and what I wanted to do was to save every String splitted in a Dictionary as Key . and valueKey was its child .

heres my class :

```
class RfClass
{
   public Dictionary<string, RfClass> lstRefClass = new Dictionary<string, RfClass>();
}
```

and my dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, RfClass> lstRefClass = new Dictionary<string, RfClass>();
```

Question:
How can i save Dictionary's Object Dictionary dynamically?

output should be (base on sample above):

```
Dictionary:
   Key: Project
   Value: Dictionary<string, RfClass>
          Key: Beta
          Value: Dictionary<string, RfClass>
                 Key: Version
                 Value: Dictionary<string, RfClass>
                        Key: Rule
                        Value: Dictionary<string, RfClass>
          Key: Program
          Value: Dictionary<string, RfClass>
                 Key: Table
                 Value: Dictionary<string, RfClass>
   Key: Zip
   Value Dictionary<string, RfClass>
         Key: File
         Value: Dictionary<string, RfClass>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'save'? In a file or in a string or something similar? Are you aware of of the xml serilalization facilities of the .NET framework?

Comment: Do you need to use dictionary or is it OK to use any other method?

Comment: @Codor, save in Dictionary

Comment: @danish, can be other method if its easier and more accessible to use ... but no db related

Comment: In your example, what would be the value for the key `Beta`?

Comment: @Codor i updated the Question ... value should be an instance of Dictionary<string, RfClass> then if Text has child(e.g Version) same process ...

Comment: @Elegiac so you need Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,RfClass>>() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle which i have created

https://dotnetfiddle.net/W54ImW

it should help you, i suppose

full code of example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{

    List<string> lstString = new List<string>();
    lstString.Add("Project.Beta.Version.Rule");     
    lstString.Add("Project.Program.Table");
    lstString.Add("Project.Program");
    lstString.Add("Zip.File");

    var root = new RfClass();

    foreach(var x in lstString)
    {
        string[] words = x.Split('.');
        CreateTree(root, words, 0);
    }

    Display(root);
}   

public static void CreateTree(RfClass root, string[] words, int idx)
{
    RfClass next;
    if (false == root.lstRefClass.TryGetValue(words[idx], out next))
    {
        next = new RfClass();
        root.lstRefClass.Add(words[idx], next);
    }
    if (idx + 1 < words.Length)
        CreateTree(next, words, idx + 1);
}

public static void Display(RfClass root, int indent = 0)
{
    foreach(var p in root.lstRefClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} key: {1} ",new string('\t', indent), p.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Value: Dictionary<string, RfClass>", new string('\t', indent));
        Display(p.Value, indent+1);
    }
}

public class RfClass
{
   public Dictionary<string, RfClass> lstRefClass = new Dictionary<string, RfClass>();
}
}
```